# Number of $3$-digit numbers with digits in descending order

Tags: combinatorics

**Question:**

> How many $3$-digit numbers are possible in which the digits are in descending order?

Now, I did: $\frac{9\times9\times8}6$ while the video did: $\frac{10\times9\times8}6$.

As apparent, the video considered all possible digits that can come in $3$ places and then dividing by $6$ will leave only those $3$-digit numbers with their digits in descending order.
Now I also reasoned exactly the same but naturally, hundred's digit can't have $0$ so didn't include it but in my mental imagery all the numbers were resulting in what was asked by the question. I know I'm wrong. But I can't "see" (mentally) how/why?
Please help.

Note: I'm not really interested in solving the question by some other method though I'll be glad to know them. My main concern is to check and correct my logical fallacy so I can tackle similar problems in the future without repeating the same mistake.

**Edit:**
Further explanation of the thought process involved into $\frac{9\times9\times8}6$:
The $100$s' digit may contain digits from $1$ to $9$, then $10$s' digit may contain numbers from $0$ to $9$ except the digit now $100$'s place is using. Finally, unit's place may also contain digits form $0$ to $9$ except the digits now $100$s' and $10$s' place are using. Now I multiply them: $9\times9\times8$. Now to select the ones with specific descending order, I divide by $6$.

Comment: The first digit can't be one but the last digit can be.  He's not picking the digits in order of their place values.  He's just picking the three different digits. And in decreasing order the $0$ will *not* be in first so we don't need to worry about making a case for it.

Comment: It is a matter of choosing exactly $3$ distinct digits and after rhat ordering them in descending order. Because the order is descending it will be automatically that the first digit will not be zero. Things would be different by ascending order.

Comment: @fleablood I get the logical plausibility of the video's approach as you have now explained too. My confusion is that I too see the numbers rearranging themselves in descending order despite not including 0 as a candidate for 100s' place.

Comment: @drhab please read the above comment, couldn't tag more than 1 person in same comment

Comment: Why do you have $9\times9\times8$ as numerator? I suspect the first $9$ corresponds with the first digit (no $0$). However there are only $8$ options for the first digit. This because of the descending order.

Comment: @drhab Because 100s' digit may contain digits from 1 to 9, then 10s' digit may contain numbers from 0 to 9 except the digit now 100's place is using. Finally, unit's place may also contain digits form 0 to 9 except the digits now 100s' and 10s' place are using. Now I multiply them: 9x9x8. Now to select the ones with specific descending order, I divide by 6.

Comment: To get more grip on intuition solve the following: we only allow the digits $0$ and $1$. "How many $2$-digit numbers are there that have digits in strictly descending order?" It is evident that the correct answer is $1$ (only $10$ works) but according to your reasoning we get $\frac{1\times1}2=0.5$ which is absurd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the other answers have explained, $\frac{10\cdot9\cdot8}{6}=8\cdot3\cdot5=120$ is the correct answer. To show why your answer is wrong, I'm first going to make an educated guess about how you came to your solution.

> For a 3 digit number, there are $9$ choices for the first digit, $9$ choices for the second, and $8$ for the third. Thus there are $9\cdot9\cdot8$ three-digit numbers with unique digits.
>
> Now for every set of 3 numbers, $\color{red}{\text{there are 6 three-digit numbers}}$, only one of which is sorted in decreasing order. Thus the number of descending three-digit numbers is one-sixth of the total amount of three-digit numbers with distinct digits.
>
> Thus there are $\frac{9\cdot9\cdot8}{6}$ three-digit numbers with digits sorted in decreasing order.

Note the expression in red. It is false. This is because, when excluding numbers that start with zero, you've made it so that sets of three numbers which contain zero only appear 4 times among the 3-digit numbers.

With this knowledge, you *can* correct your solution by tracking the numbers with zero separately.

> There are $9\cdot8\cdot7$ numbers with no zeros, $9\cdot1\cdot8$ numbers with a zero in the tens place, and $9\cdot8\cdot1$ numbers with a zero in the ones place. This gives a total of $9\cdot8\cdot2$ numbers with a zero.
>
> From the numbers with no zeros, there are six numbers per set of digits with one decreasing. Thus we get $\frac{9\cdot8\cdot7}{6}=4\cdot3\cdot7$ decreasing numbers from here.
>
> From the numbers with a zero, there are four numbers per set of digits, with one decreasing. Thus we get $\frac{9\cdot8\cdot2}{4}=4\cdot9$ decreasing numbers.
>
> Adding these totals together, we get $(4\cdot3\cdot7)+(4\cdot9)=12\cdot(7+3)=120$ numbers with decreasing digits.

Which is the amount given by the solutions.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Greatly explained. Now I get it. Upvoted. Also, could you please address this too: How to not make such a mistake? Should I never treat a 3-digit number as a 3 digit number but as an array of length 3 with only digits allowed, for probability and combinatorics purposes? Will this change help me or do you have an even better suggestion?

Comment: @InanimateBeing I think just being aware of (or going back though and listing) what assumptions and generalizations you're making would go a long way. In a counting problem, consider what effect any exclusion has on the remainder of your argument. For a more specific tip, no exclusions are "more important" than others, and even if they were they don't have to be first--in this case there's no reason to exclude $063$ in an earlier step than $482$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's what I wanted. Amazing. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, though not explicitly written in the question, what is wanted is three digit numbers in **strictly** descending order.

Anyway, don't visualize it as hundreds digit and so on, just a block of three different digits.

When arranged in strictly descending order, a $0$, if it is used at all, must necessarily be in the units position.

Comment: I'm not able to convey my problem yet I think. I want to know why $\frac {9\times9\times8}6$ is not working?

Comment: If 0's were not allowed at all, then there would be only $\frac{9\times8\times7}{6} = 84$ solutions.  Allowing a 0 in the units place lets us choose $\frac{9\times8}{2} = 36$ permutations of the first two places.  Thus, total number of solutions is 84 + 36 = 120.

Comment: @Dan got it, thanks. This is a nice way to deal with 0 too.

Answer (score 2):

To get more grip on intuition solve the following:

If we only allow the digits $0$ and $1$ and also in this case the first digit is not allowed to be $0$ then:

> "How many $2$-digit numbers are there that have digits in strictly descending order?"

It is evident that the correct answer is $1$ (only $10$ works) but according to your reasoning we get $\frac{1\times1}2=0.5$ which is absurd.

I advice you to think about this. It is the same problem but made "smaller". That can be healthy if your intuition has some blind spot.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Great example! It really helps understand the fallacy in our logic and that's always the first step towards solution.

Comment: Glad to hear that.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether you're allowed to have duplicated digits.  If they must be three *distinct* digits, then there are ${10 \choose 3} = 120$ possible combinations of digits, each with exactly one way to arrange those digits in descending order.

However, with duplicate digits allowed, there are 99 additional possibilities: 9 with all three digits the same (111, 222, 333, ..., 999), 45 (=9+8+7+...+1) with duplicated first/second digits, and 45 with duplicated second/third digits.    This raises the total number of descending-digit numbers to 219.

The video's answer of $\frac{10 \times 9 \times 8}{6} = 120$ indicates the assumption of distinct digits.  I don't know where you got $\frac{9 \times 9 \times 8}{6} = 108$ from.

Comment: I have added an "edit" in my question, please check.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your efforts. Upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

I already know there're ${9} \choose {3}$ = 84 numbers of three distinct digits in increasing order with no zeros in them (because there's no way a 0 can be in a increasing order number between 100 and 999).

Check: Number of $3$-digit numbers with strictly increasing digits, URL (version: 2023-08-22): https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4756655

This implies there are 84 numbers (with no zero) in decreasing order, which are the reversals of the ones in increasing order. E.g: 321 is the reversal of 123.

Then you have to find how many numbers in decreasing order are there with a 0 as its third digit. Because there's no way it can be the first or middle digit!.

This is a problem that can be solved thinking in how many numbers of two digits in decreasing order are there.

This is ${{9} \choose {2}} $ numbers.

Then there're ${{9} \choose {2}} + {{9} \choose {3}}  = 36 + 84 = 120$ numbers of three distinct digits in decreasing order.

Answer (score 0):

He's not picking the digits in order.  His picking the digits. period.  There are three digits and they can be any combination of three numbers.  There are ${10\choose 3}$ ways to choose them.  For each combination there is exactly one way to arrange them in descending order.  And if there is a $0$ it will be at the end so that's acceptable.

Had the problem been how many in ascending order then you can not have $0$ in your three digits at all (else it would have to begin with $0$) and the answer would be ${9\choose 3} =\frac{9\cdot 8\cdot 7}6$

Comment: I get the logical plausibility of the video's approach as you have now explained too. My confusion is that I too see the numbers rearranging themselves in descending order despite not including 0 as a candidate for 100s' place.